# how to get Jsoup element

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

```
<li data-test-component="ProductStats" class="sc-qVkRw dDEgow">
    <dl data-test-component="DescriptionList" class="sc-ejxegM hEIIuR">
        <dt labelwidth="208px" labelwidthmobile="168px" class="sc-cOxWqc sc-hIsuHl kWkcWl fhKhnO">В избранном</dt>
        <dd labelwidth="208px" labelwidthmobile="168px" class="sc-cOxWqc sc-fVmuvm eOPaPs dVayGV">1</dd>
        <dt labelwidth="208px" labelwidthmobile="168px" class="sc-cOxWqc sc-hIsuHl kWkcWl fhKhnO">Просмотры</dt>
        <dd labelwidth="208px" labelwidthmobile="168px" class="sc-cOxWqc sc-fVmuvm eOPaPs dVayGV">2</dd>
        <dt labelwidth="208px" labelwidthmobile="168px" class="sc-cOxWqc sc-hIsuHl kWkcWl fhKhnO">Размещено</dt>
        <dd labelwidth="208px" labelwidthmobile="168px" class="sc-cOxWqc sc-fVmuvm eOPaPs dVayGV">Сегодня в 13:52</dd>
    </dl>
</li>
```

The element itself looks like this. I need to get "Сегодня в 13:52".

Through xpath, this would be done like this >> //li [@data-test-component = 'ProductStats'], And further through href. I don't understand how to implement selector in jsoup

Tried to copy the selector via F12

Comment: I forgot to add "Today at 13:52" dynamic, so it makes no sense to search simply by text.

Comment: Can you share the link to the page? If the content is filled with JavaScript after the page loads Jsoup might be not the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that you are aiming for text of last child of dl element

```
Document doc =  Jsoup.parse("<li data-test-component=\"ProductStats\" class=\"sc-qVkRw dDEgow\"><dl data-test-component=\"DescriptionList\" class=\"sc-ejxegM hEIIuR\"><dt labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-hIsuHl kWkcWl fhKhnO\">В избранном</dt><dd labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-fVmuvm eOPaPs dVayGV\">1</dd><dt labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-hIsuHl kWkcWl fhKhnO\">Просмотры</dt><dd labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-fVmuvm eOPaPs dVayGV\">2</dd><dt labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-hIsuHl kWkcWl fhKhnO\">Размещено</dt><dd labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-fVmuvm eOPaPs dVayGV\">Сегодня в 13:52</dd></dl></li>");
    Elements elList = doc.body().select("li[data-test-component='ProductStats']");
    if(elList!=null && elList.size()>0 && elList.get(0).childNodeSize()>0){
        Element liElement= elList.get(0);
        if(liElement.childNodeSize()>0){
            if(liElement.childNodeSize()>0){
                Element firstChildElOfLi = liElement.child(0);
                Element targetEl = firstChildElOfLi.child(firstChildElOfLi.childNodeSize()-1);
                System.out.println(targetEl.text());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: classes are dynamic, on each page their name is different.

Comment: @Artist as long as data-test-component attribute of li tag is same and you want text of last child of dl tag, given code works fine as it does not have any class name dependency

Comment: @ﾓｷｬﾃﾞ that was good, one line solution but what if first child of li element is not dl, in that case how would you approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you need with a single `selectFirst` method.

```
String html = "<li data-test-component=\"ProductStats\" class=\"sc-qVkRw dDEgow\">\r\n"
    + "    <dl data-test-component=\"DescriptionList\" class=\"sc-ejxegM hEIIuR\">\r\n"
    + "        <dt labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-hIsuHl kWkcWl fhKhnO\">В избранном</dt>\r\n"
    + "        <dd labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-fVmuvm eOPaPs dVayGV\">1</dd>\r\n"
    + "        <dt labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-hIsuHl kWkcWl fhKhnO\">Просмотры</dt>\r\n"
    + "        <dd labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-fVmuvm eOPaPs dVayGV\">2</dd>\r\n"
    + "        <dt labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-hIsuHl kWkcWl fhKhnO\">Размещено</dt>\r\n"
    + "        <dd labelwidth=\"208px\" labelwidthmobile=\"168px\" class=\"sc-cOxWqc sc-fVmuvm eOPaPs dVayGV\">Сегодня в 13:52</dd>\r\n"
    + "    </dl>\r\n"
    + "</li>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element e = doc.selectFirst("li[data-test-component=ProductStats] > dl > :last-child");
System.out.println(e.text());
```

OUTPUT:

```
Сегодня в 13:52
```